# Salvaging a broken Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, service-application

The Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application and its associated proxy on my farm are broken and preventing workflows from publishing correctly. I'd like to just destroy and re-provision them from scratch, but when I try to use `Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy` or `Remove-SPServiceApplication` on them, I get the message `This service application proxy is required for the farm to function correctly and cannot be deleted.`

Google returned exactly one result on the subject, [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/82aafde9-6c36-444e-81cc-4bdd46f23166/unable-to-delete-application-discovery-and-load-balancer-service-application-proxy?forum=sharepointadminprevious). Unfortunately this farm is being actively used and while rebuilding it from scratch isn't out of the option, it would be a huge time investment. Is there some other way to salvage it, or at least remove it by force so I can recreate it?

Comment: if you run the Get-SPServiceInstance then what is the status of ADLBS service?

Comment: Well it took some digging because there are apparently two of them in the farm, but when I finally got it the status is "Disabled". This is weird because in CA it says it's running

Comment: exactly that is the problem most of time, having 2 services...did you disable the one which you dont want. here is the link https://cherpoint.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/service-application-proxies/

Comment: See that's where I'm stumped, when I try that I get the error mentioned in the question about not being able to delete it

Comment: so you have two ADLBS services instance? right? are you getting 2 proxies? Get-SPServiceApplicationProx

Comment: No there's only one proxy showing up, but I can't seem to delete either service app or the proxy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69560/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-thanby).

Comment: [Appologize as I used the answer instead of the comment. Unfortunatly can not delete it when trying to fix it] Dear thanby, how did you happened to solve this issue? Did you indeed end up rebuilding the Farm? Thanks in advance. Best regards, GS